# Easier way to solve $\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\lfloor{}1-\log_2(x)\rfloor}$

Tags: definite-integrals, summation

This problem showed up in the MIT integration bee last year:
$$\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\lfloor{}1-\log_2(x)\rfloor}$$

Basically, after doing a lot of tedious work I graphed out part of the function and noticed that the function was just a bunch of rectangles. The width of rectangle $n$ was $2^{-n}$ and the height was $\frac1n$ so the total area was:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}({2^{-n}})(\frac1{n})$$

After some more work I recognized this to be the taylor series of $-\ln(1-x)$ evaluated at $x=\frac12$ and since $-\ln(1-\frac12)=\ln(2)$, I concluded that the integral was equal to $\ln(2)$, which some numerical integration verified for me.

My question is, is there any easier way to do this that maybe isn't so tedious?

Comment: I don't think that your way is tedious - it is clever. I think you ought to add your proof (either to the question or as an answer).

Comment: @martycohen I can imagine having to verify things with numerical stuff, and only guessing at what the actual sum should be is rather tedious since it's not certain that this is the right sum nor the right value, though I agree, changing it to the sum is undoubtedly what they intended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's see, if you do $u=1-\log_2 x$ then

$$-2^{1-u}(\log 2)\, du=dx$$

Then you get

$$(\log 2)\cdot \int_{1}^\infty{2^{1-u}\over \lfloor u\rfloor}\,du$$

This is clearly

$$2(\log 2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}{2^{-u}\over \lfloor u\rfloor}\,du$$

But on the interval $[n,n+1)$ **by definition** the floor function is equal to $n$, so the integrand is just ${2^{-u}\over n}$ on that interval, which allows us to rewrite this as

$$2(\log 2)\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n}\int_n^{n+1}2^{-u}\,du$$

the inner integral is easily seen to be

$$\left({1\over2\log 2}\right)2^{-n}$$

and of course this gives

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n2^n}=\log 2$$

Of course this is still the same sum, but you don't have to do any guessing, it's all definitely the right thing, without experimenting--and you don't need any numerical tests to verify it as a guess.

Comment: Can you explain how you went from equation #2 to equation #3 please?

Comment: @ASKASK I have edited my answer to have an extra step to explain that one.

Comment: Do you know of any ways of proving the value of the sum other than with the taylor series of $\ln(1-x)$?

Comment: @ASKASK Not really, it's **the** standard thing to do for evaluating that sort of series is to use the log power series (or integrate the geometric series if you've forgotten the log one).

Answer (score 0):

$$\lfloor 1 - \log_2 x \rfloor = \lfloor \log_2 2 - \log_2 x \rfloor = \left\lfloor \log_2 \frac{2}{x} \right\rfloor.$$ Now note $$n \le \log_2 \frac{2}{x} < n+1$$ whenever $2^{n-1} \le \frac{1}{x} < 2^n$, or equivalently, $$2^{-n} < x \le 2^{1-n}.$$  So we immediately have $$\int_{x=0}^1 \frac{dx}{\lfloor 1 - \log_2 x \rfloor} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} (2^{1-n} - 2^{-n}) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n 2^n}.$$  Now consider the geometric series $$\frac{1}{1-z} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n, \quad |z| < 1. $$  Integration with respect to $z$ gives $$-\log(1-z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1} = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n}, \quad |z| < 1.$$  Now for $z = 1/2$ we find the integral has value $-\log(1-\tfrac{1}{2}) = \log 2$.